# Multiple variable integration of a function of multiple variables

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, integral-equations

I'm having trouble writing code in Mathematica for this multi variable integration:
$\int_0^1\int_0^1...\int_0^1F[x_1,x_2,...,x_n]dx_1dx_2...dx_n$

If I already know the number of elements of A it is easy:
`Integrate[F[x1,x2],{x1,0,1},{x2,0,1}]`. I also tried using `Nest[Integrate[#,{?,0,1]&, F[x],Length[X]}` but for `?` I have no idea what to use.

Also how should I define the $x$s? I have defined `F[_X]` with `X` being a vector (I have a certain function in mind).

Comment: Try this: `Integrate[F @@ X, Sequence @@ Thread[{X, 0, 1}]]`

Comment: @AnjanKumar thank you, it works. With X = {a,b,c,d}, doing F @@ X is like calling F[a,b,c,d] based on what I read now. But how does Sequence @@ Thread work?

Comment: `Sequence@@` basically removes the external brackets and `Thread` creates a list of `{xi, 0, 1}` where xi is an element of X. I would suggest you to go through the documentation to get a good feel of those functions.